# getting a ptty for docker start

Tags: docker

Docker's `run` and `exec` command both allow the `-t` flag to get a psuedo-terminal. This works nicely for something like: `docker run -it --name deb debian bash`. Once the user exits the interactive bash shell in this container, the container stops. While the `exec` command could similarly take the same flag and would work well doing so, the stopped container may not have anything executed within unless it is started.

The start command does not take the `-t` flag. Using just `-ai` with say, `docker start -ai deb` would run `bash` again but fail to show an interactive prompt, making use kind of... cumbersome. Without `-ai` the bash process would just exit, making the container stop right after starting.

While this sub-optimal attached, interactive, bash is open, <kbd>^z</kbd> will not background the current docker command. If however you open a new terminal, setup your docker environment variables correctly, and now, finally, issue `docker exec -it deb bash`, you can get back to the nicer interactive bash prompt when you first started the container.

This seems quite involved. Am I missing something about start or exec that might make it easier to use bash or another interactive command? Perhaps there is some preferred command to run that will never exit, keep the container running (until told to stop) and use very little processor time so as to make exec the preferred method of attaching to an interactive process in the container.

Comment: if you launch a container with something like `docker run -it ubuntu sh -c "while true; do echo world; sleep 98; done"` then when you do `docker exec -it container_id bash` and then you do CTRL D, the container does not stop

Comment: @user2915097 True; you don't even need an echo and with bash you wouldn't need the true either. One could `tail -f /dev/null` which never closes or some sleep command versions accept `infinity`. However, is there some docker idiomatic reason `start` doesn't handle `-t`. Is there some fancy way to simulate it with piping or something? Also I notice that even with `-t` I can't actually run `vim`, `nano`, `jed`, `jupp`, `emacs` due to the lack of an obvious terminal/tty.